# Databinding to enumeration of a static class

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Chaps,
I have a datagrid and am colouring the rows as follows.

```
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
             </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorType}" Value="TerminalError">
                 <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="Purple"/>
            </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorType}" Value="CriticalError">
                <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Currently the colours are hard-coded and I need to change this. I have a singleton class that holds colours for different states and colours may be accessed in the following way:

```
Color returnedColour = ColourSchemes.Instance.GetColour (CriticalError)
```

So in the xaml, where I have Value="Red" etc, I wish to source the name from the globally accessible ColourSchemes object instead. Would very much appreciate any words of wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, make sure to use Brush instead of Color what you assign a value to a property like Foreground or Background.

Then you may add an indexer property to your ColourSchemes class, which takes the enum value as key:

```
public enum ErrorType
{
    TerminalError, CriticalError
}

public class ColourSchemes
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ErrorType, Brush> brushes =
        new Dictionary<ErrorType, Brush>
        {
            { ErrorType.TerminalError, Brushes.Orange },
            { ErrorType.CriticalError, Brushes.Red }
        };

    public Brush this[ErrorType value]
    {
        get { return brushes[value]; }
    }

    public static ColourSchemes Instance { get; } = new ColourSchemes();
}
```

Now you may bind a property like this:

```
Background="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ColourSchemes.Instance}, Path=[CriticalError]}">
```

Or in a Setter:

```
<Setter Property="Background"
    Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ColourSchemes.Instance}, Path=[CriticalError]}"/>
```

---

You may however want to take a look at [Dynamic Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#static-and-dynamic-resources).

Comment: Your answer was spot on Clemens. I had to modify it a bit as my ColourSchemes class can't be changed, but given the information it was a splendid answer.